# JFrog Cloud - custom artifactory.system.properties?

Tags: artifactory

In JFrog Cloud, is there a way to add custom settings to the artifactory.system.properties file?

We'd like to enable numeric sorting in the artifact tree browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach out to JFrog Support team who helps in changing the values according to your need.